# Coerce rat to realType im math-comp/analysis

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

Is there a way to coerce a rat into a realType (from the math-comp/analysis library)? For example, the notation for coercing a nat is %:R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/b60e80c3d9a46e804a8faa9ae9e379c71d9a83ca/mathcomp/algebra/rat.v#L22) `ratr` coerces a `rat` to any unit ring (hence any `realType`).